# Minimum of $a+b$

Tags: optimization, integers

> Suppose that $a,b$ are integers such that
>
> $$a^2 b = 72$$
>
> How can we minimize $a+b$?

We must require that $b>0$ as $a^2>0$.

$$a^2 = \frac{72}{b}$$

Among the divisors of $72$, only $b\in \{2, 8, 18, 72\}$ will give us a perfect square, so choose $b = 2$ and get $a = \pm 6$ so that $a+b = -4$ is its minimum.

Is there a better/faster approach here?

Comment: That really seems optimal.  Note that, if you drop the integrality requirement, there is no minimum....so continuous methods aren't going to help here.  You'll need to look at the squares which divide $72$, just as you did.

Comment: @lulu Thank you!