# Maximum/minimum of $xyz$

Tags: optimization, integers

> Suppose that $x, y, z$ are positive integers such that
>
> $$xy = 48$$
>
> $$yz = 60$$
>
> How can we maximize and minimize $xyz$?

As suggested in comments,

$$xyz = \frac{48\times 60}{y} = \frac{2880}{y}$$

Which takes its minimum at $y = 12$, so $xyz = \frac{2880}{12} = 240$.

Comment: As with your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4853152/minimum-of-ab), integrality is the key here.  $y$ must be a divisor of $\gcd(48,60)=12$.  So just test all the factors of $12$.

Comment: @Keane There are typos in your reasoning. $x+y$ should be $x+z$ a couple of times.

Comment: @Aig Thanks, edited

Comment: @lulu Yes, you're right.

Comment: Notice that $7^3$ is unachievable since none of the $x,y,z$ is divisible by $7$.

Comment: In combination with @lulu 's comment, note that $xyz=\frac{48\cdot 60}{y}=\frac{2880}{y}$, and you're done.

Comment: As I have tested by myself, setting $(x,y,z)=(4,12,5)$ [that you have considered to be maximum] is the minimum, while $(x,y,z)=(24,2,30)$ is the maximum. You can try considering the equation $xyz=2880/y$ and set $y=12$ for the least value and $y=2$ for the greatest one.

Comment: Writing $xyz = \frac{2880}{y}$ helps a lot :)

Comment: @M.Riyan why $y=2$ and not $y=1$?

Comment: @Henry it was in fact a typo. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x,y,z>0$, thus we have no issues with sign changes or division by zero. As you noted: $x=\frac{48}y$ and $z=\frac{60}y$ and thus:

$$xyz = \frac{2880}{y}.$$

This function is strictly, monotonically decreasing. Now we use the fact that $x,y,z$ are integers and thus $x,y$ divide $48$ and $y,z$ divide $60$.

Let $M_{48}=\{1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,48\}$ is the set of divisors for $48$ and $M_{60}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60\}$.

$y$ can only take values out of $M_{48}\cap M_{60}=\{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$. Thus the minimum value is $\frac{2880}{12}=240$ and its maximum value is $\frac{2880}{1}=2880$.

A complete value table for integer solutions is here
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & y & z & xyz \\ \hline
48 & 1  & 60 & 2880 \\ \hline
24 & 2  & 30 & 1440 \\ \hline
16 & 3  & 20 & 960  \\ \hline
12 & 4  & 15 & 720  \\ \hline
8  & 6  & 10 & 480  \\ \hline
4  & 12 & 5  & 240  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$